# Could not load requested class : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver on Tomcat & IntelliJ

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am getting this error when I'm running my application in IntelliJ using Tomcat Server:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I tried adding the MySQL library, but with no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "I tried adding the MySQL library" => Where and what exactly did you try to _add_? Your question needs much more detailed information. As it is, we can't help you.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I added a downloaded JAR to my libraries, but it was not seen because I didn't include it in the artifact, as the answer from below suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a library to the artifact that gets deployed to the application server you need to do the following:

### 1. Download the desired library

- In IntelliJ you will need to go to **File** > **Project Structure** > **Libraries**
- Click the **+** (plus) button to add a New Project Library
- If you select the **Java** option, you will be asked for the jar of that library (that you have already downloaded)
- If you select the **Maven** option, you can search for the desired library, but I suggest using the [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/) to search for the library you need. If you find it, in the IntelliJ dialog box that just opened you can give the exact Maven coordinates in the form *group*:*artifact*:*version* (for the MySQL driver it might be mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.13)

### 2. Add the library to the artifact

- Under **File** > **Project Structure** > **Artifacts**, select the **Output Layout** tab
- In the **WEB-INF** folder create a **lib** folder if you do not have it already
- Right click on the **lib** folder > **Add Copy of** > **Library files**, and choose the library that you added at step **1.**
- Click ok to close the **Project Structure** window

This should make your program work correctly.

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks a lot!